# How to let the UICollectionView cell can be multil-selected in its setSelected: method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

This is my UICollectionView:

[image]

And in the Collection Cell, there is a `setSelected:` method I can se the cell be selected color:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {

    [super setSelected:selected];

    //self.selected = !selected;

    // checked
    if (selected) {
        self.backView.backgroundColor = APP_COLOR;
        self.number_label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.multiple_label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }
    // uncheck
    else {

        self.backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.number_label.textColor = HexRGB(0x999999);
        self.multiple_label.textColor = HexRGB(0xcccccc);
    }
}
```

But in my tableView, if I click the other cell, the selected cell will be uncheck, so there only one cell is checked in the cell.

So, how can I multil-select the cell in UICollectionView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set [`allowsMultipleSelection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618024-allowsmultipleselection?language=objc) to `YES`:

> A Boolean value that determines whether users can select more than one item in the collection view.
>
> This property controls whether multiple items can be selected simultaneously. The default value of this property is **false**.
> When the value of this property is **true**, tapping a cell adds it to the current selection (assuming the delegate permits the cell to be selected). Tapping the cell again removes it from the selection.

Comment: Thank you, and other question is how can I know which cell is selected by me if I multil-selected some cell?

Comment: @s-n-2 you can get index paths of selected cells by calling [`collectionView. indexPathsForSelectedItems`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618099-indexpathsforselecteditems?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

Both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` has `@property (nonatomic) BOOL allowsMultipleSelection; // default is NO` Set it to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is store indexPath in array on didSelectItemAtIndexPath and check in array if its already exist then remove other add in array.In cellForItemAtIndexPath method compare indexPath in array.